# window.location.href is not working from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

I wanted to open the link from the popup window in same window and then close the popup window.

I got this which was similar to what I was looking for: [open the link from the popup window in an external window and then close the original popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905830/open-the-link-from-the-popup-window-in-an-external-window-and-then-close-the-ori)

I tried the solution of that and its closing the popup which I wanted but not redirecting to the specified url.

I have PHP page e.g Page A in which I have used popup window as I mentioned in [loading php page with class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675217/loading-php-page-with-class-in-javascript)

now, on correct.php which opens in popup window, I have a button. For that I used the solution as below which is not redirecting to url :

```
<input type="button"  value="Search" ONCLICK="window.location.href='https://www.google.co.in/';parent.$.colorbox.close();">
```

what may be the reason for not opening the specified url?

Answer (score 1):

just create two php page user.php and user_admin.php. Copy and paste the code . first run user_admin.php . it will opens user.php using script . after user.php code runs . pop up window will close. function closeBrowser(){ self.close(); }  this is script to close pop up window

```
user_admin.php
<html><head>
</head>
<body onLoad="clickButton()">
<script>
var pop = new Array();
function myFunction() {
pop[0] = window.open("http://user.php");
pop[1] = window.close();
}
</script>
<script>
function clickButton()
{
document.getElementById('button1').click();
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="button1" onClick="myFunction()" value="Button 1" />
</body>
</html>

user.php

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeBrowser(){
    self.close();
}
</script>
</head>
 <body onLoad="closeBrowser();">

<!-- Write your code here -->
 </body>
</html>
```

I Hope this will help you . Try it once .

Comment: @ user3824319 : I am little confused. Can you please explain your answer? So that I can try it with my code.  thanks.